# ScreenUpdating x On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Com o código abaixo:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Código

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Código caso erro

End Sub
```

ScreenUpdating = False vindo antes de On Error GoTo ErrorHandler no código, interfere na aplicação do On Error?

Comment: Uma explicação em inglês que eu gosto muito é [deste site](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/). Não interfere na aplicação do `On Error`, basta fazer um teste inserindo uma divisão por zero `x = 1 / 0`. Verá que o `On Error` é aplicado corretamente. Percorra o código passo-a-passo com a tecla `F8`.

Comment: Muito bom esse site.

Answer (score 2):

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False` desativa a atualização de tela e sempre no final do código você tem que ativar `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. Não interfere em `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` mas `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` que está depois, não será executado caso não acorra alguma erro.
Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Código
fin:
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

'Código caso erro

GoTo fin
```

Assim, mesmo que não dê erro ou caso ocorra algum erro, irá ativar a atualização de tela antes de finalizar em `Exit Sub`

Comment: Ou ao invés de fazer um `fin:` e `GoTo`, inserir os códigos de finalização em `ErrorHandler:`

Comment: Mas se não der erro não vai executar `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. A execução não chegará em **ErrorHandler**.

Comment: Verdade, é que eu utilizo `ErrHandler:` de outra  maneira, ai usa um `If Err.Number <> 0 Then`. Mas desta maneira funciona, só estava dando outra sugestão de como realizar. Ou você cria uma função para tratar cada tipo de erro.

Comment: Boa tarde a todos!
Mesmo invertendo a ordem entre as duas linhas de código, o problema continua.
No meu caso, é quando utilizo ListObjects para acessar Tabelas.
Se eu sem querer trocar o nome da planilha ou da Tabela, a macro para no erro tradicional, quando para mim deveria cair no OnError.
Vou fechar o tópico e abrir outro mais específico.

Comment: Aí o problema é outro. Você pode alterar esse post com outro título e os dados que contém o erro.